# NoClassDefFoundError for IndentingXMLStreamWriter class in stax-utils.jar

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, stax

I am writing an XML file with StAX parser using XmlStreamEventWriter, the stax-utils.jar is added correctly to the classpath in Eclipse. I wanted to use `IndentingXMLStreamWriter` class from this jar file but somehow its throwing below exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javanet/staxutils/IndentingXMLStreamWriter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javanet.staxutils.IndentingXMLStreamWriter 
           cannot be found by RCP_PLUGIN_6.20.0.qualifier
```

The piece of code causing exception is :

```
XMLEventFactory eventFactory=XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
if(!tmpSettingsXml.exists())
    tmpSettingsXml.createNewFile();
XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter=new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().
                    createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(tmpSettingsXml)));
xmlStreamWriter.writeStartDocument();
```

If the method containing 'IndentingXMLStreamWriter' is being called from other class of the tool its throwing exception, however, if this method is called from main() in other class its perfectly working fine and able to find classes inside jar.

Anyone can suggest what's wrong here?

Comment: What does "added correctly to the classpath" actually mean here?

Comment: @nitind It means in Eclipse, right click on project, configure build path and stax-utils.jar is added there with "add jar" option.

Comment: This exception happens running within an Eclipse plug-in?

Comment: @nitind yes, basically it's a RCP product made up of plugins and features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Eclipse/RCP plug-in runs within an OSGi Runtime, which (almost) completely controls its runtime classpath based on the Plug-in Manifest: the **MANIFEST.MF** file. You need to add any dependencies that aren't your own sources *there*, and not directly using the Java Build Path UI. The Java Build Path UI isn't locked out because a Plug-in Project is still a Java Project, just with more stuff.

So remove the jar(s) you added to the Java Build Path, open the MANIFEST.MF file in the Plug-in Manifest Editor, and add the jars to the Classpath section on the Runtime tab.

[image: The Plug-in Manifest Editor's Runtime page]

Comment: thanks, it works when jar file is added to that plugin itself,but just a doubt, I have added jar to plugin A's(where all jars required for product are kept) manifest, now plugin A is added into dependencies of plugin B, now trying to access classes from plugin A's jar into plugin B is not possible.

Comment: @user3462473 add what you need to using the Exported Packages section of the same page, but only after giving a little thought to why another plug-in needs the same classes--is this a dependency you want to leak into being API.